# What were the old names of the "describe" and "it" methods in rspec?

Tags: rspec

I find the method names `describe` and `it` in rspec to be a bit counter-intuitive. I read [here](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2007/05/14/an-introduction-to-rspec-part-i/) that those two methods used to have different names in earlier versions of rspec but after a bit of googling haven't been able to discover what they were.

Does anyone know what former names of the `it` and `describe` methods in rspec?

Hoping this might give me a better sense of what they're meant to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/bbc83cee645ddd44049b31960ed9f914a0884691/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L78):

> ...early versions of RSpec which used `context` and `specify` instead of `describe` and `it`.

Looking at the code here, you can use either `it`, `example`, or `specify`. So the following are equivalent:

```
describe School do

  it 'has many students' {}

  specify 'has many students' {}

  example 'has many students' {}

end
```

The [alias for `describe`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/bbc83cee645ddd44049b31960ed9f914a0884691/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb#L232), `context`, is still valid and used by may RSpec'ers. Normally, within the outer `describe` block providing  more details.

This:

```
describe School do

  context 'requesting the student roster' do
    it '...'
  end

end
```

Instead of:

```
describe School do

  describe '#roster' do
    it '...'
  end

end
```